# Wrong hash value when requesting access token from Twitter API

Tags: python, twitter-oauth

I am following this tutorial [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/guides/log-in-with-twitter#tab1) by Twitter on how to implement a 3-legged oauth flow. Particularly I am stuck on generating a signature. When I follow the [how to generate a signature tutorial](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a/creating-a-signature) that works and I can verify the signature, like so:

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
digest = hmac.new("kAcSOqF21Fu85e7zjz7ZN2U4ZRhfV3WpwPAoE3Z7kBw&LswwdoUaIvS8ltyTt5jkRh4J50vUPVVHtR2YPi5kE".encode(), "POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1.1%2Fstatuses%2Fupdate.json&include_entities%3Dtrue%26oauth_consumer_key%3Dxvz1evFS4wEEPTGEFPHBog%26oauth_nonce%3DkYjzVBB8Y0ZFabxSWbWovY3uYSQ2pTgmZeNu2VS4cg%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1318622958%26oauth_token%3D370773112-GmHxMAgYyLbNEtIKZeRNFsMKPR9EyMZeS9weJAEb%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26status%3DHello%2520Ladies%2520%252B%2520Gentlemen%252C%2520a%2520signed%2520OAuth%2520request%2521".encode(), hashlib.sha1)
signature = base64.b64encode(digest.digest())
```

This produces the expected "hCtSmYh+iHYCEqBWrE7C7hYmtUk=" result.

However when I run the same code on the variables in the login tutorial, I do not get the right result, see here:

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
import urllib
digest = hmac.new("L8qq9PZyRg6ieKGEKhZolGC0vJWLw8iEJ88DRdyOg&".encode(), "POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_callback%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fsign-in-with-twitter%2F%26oauth_consumer_key%3DcChZNFj6T5R0TigYB9yd1w%26oauth_nonce%3Dea9ec8429b68d6b77cd5600adbbb0456%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1318467427%26oauth_version%3D1.0".encode(), hashlib.sha1)
signature = urllib.quote(base64.b64encode(digest.digest()))
```

This gives me the signature "52p9NEN/ZvtrV7DgroTrODYr6dM%3D" which is not the stated one in the tutorial: "F1Li3tvehgcraF8DMJ7OyxO4w9Y%3D". I am wondering how can I arrive at this signature? I am using all the same variables as the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the hash in the tutorial is indeed just wrong, do not try to program against it.